# Redirect all requests to https://www. using Apache on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, server, apache2, virtualhost, redirect

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with `Apache`.

I have the following in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to redirect all to `https` AND `www`.

These get all redirected to `https://www.example.com`:

```
https://www.example.com
http://example.com
http://www.example.com
```

This doesn't get redirected to `https://www.example.com`:

```
https://example.com
```

I also added the code with `<VirtualHost *:443>` but this doesn't help.

Why doesn't get `https://example.com` redirected to `https://www.example.com`?

Comment: "I also added the code with <VirtualHost *:443> but this doesn't help." That's the part that would be interesting to add in your post. As `https://www.example.com` will be managed by the "443 vhost" section. Do you have a `.htaccess` file in your website's root that has rewrite directive as well? If so, then rewrite directives in your vhost will be ignored if the `AllowOverride` directive allows it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force https:// and www. with virtual host apache2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/653923/force-https-and-www-with-virtual-host-apache2)

Comment: @Dan None of them is working, it seems like `<VirtualHost *:443>` gets ignored. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Solution found: There's an own file for HTTPS/SSL/433 at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`.

After I added the following code in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`, everything is working as expected now:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: When I do that, I usually do it in .htaccess. The mod_rewrite rules work in there as well. If you're curious, or want to add it to your answer, [here](https://www.elated.com/mod-rewrite-tutorial-for-absolute-beginners/) is a very basic tutorial. In this case, the same syntax you used will work in .htaccess to do the same exact thing.